# Video Capture on iOS Cordova quality

Tags: ios, cordova, video

I'm developing a mobile application that takes videos with Cordova. To make this possible I use the media-capture plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture). I have an issue with the quality on iOS, it works fine with Android but I feel like the focus on iOS is not working because the video quality is very poor if I'm not close to the object

I'm trying to find an other plugin that support good video quality with iOS but I can't find anything else, can someone please help me find a solution with the plugin, or redirect me to an other plugin that works beter ?